# How to allow ftp user acess folder outside his root directory?

Tags: linux, permissions, ftp, symbolic-link, cpanel

I am trying to create an ftp user that will have access to several folder on public_html but I don't want him to get access to all folders in public_html. Just to the specific ones.

Here is the folder structure from public_html

```
_ftpdevteam1
_ftpdevteam2
site1
site2
site3
site4
site5
site6
site7
site8
```

what I am trying to do is to create ftp user ftpdevteam1 that can access site1-4. ftpdevteam2 can access site5-8

I tried the solution on this post
http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=681872

Specifically this part

```
ln -s /home/{username}/public_html/index.html /home/{username}/{ftpusername}/index.html

ln -s /home/{username}/public_html/folder1 / /home/{username}/{ftpusername}/folder1

ln -s /home/{username}/public_html/folder2 /home/{username}/{ftpusername}/folder2
```

but when I access via filezilla I get this...

```
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/foldername"...
Command:    CWD /
Response:   250 OK. Current directory is /
Command:    CWD foldername
Response:   550 Can't change directory to foldername: No such file or directory
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Is there a way to edit permission of ftp user so they can access the folders?

I saw another solution using bind in this post
https://www.hostivate.com/blog/cpanel-ftp-user-access-multiple-folders/

but I saw in step 2 it says

```
2. We must create the above folders but in the FTP user directory
```

This doesn't seem to be a viable solution because my sites are already created folders. My understanding in this step 2 is that the real folder needs needs to reside inside _ftpdevteam1 folder.

Anyone who has any other way to be able to achieve what I am trying to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understood you need a bind mount. Try this:

```
mkdir /home/{username}/{ftpusername}/public_html
sudo mount --bind /home/{username}/public_html /home/{username}/{ftpusername}/public_html
```

Comment: Hi. Im ready to try your suggestion but it looks to me in your suggestion that ftpuser will have full access to public_html not just specific folder. I only want to give user access to some folders in public_html not the whole public_html. can you confirm? thanks

Comment: `mkdir /home/{username}/{ftpusername}/the_folder_you_need` `sudo mount --bind /home/{username}/public_html/the_folder_you_need /home/{username}/{ftpusername}/the_folder_you_need`

Comment: will this duplicate the copies of files or will only create link just like symlink?

Comment: just like symlink